# Django get_object_or_404 in details view not returning all the fields from the Page model

Tags: python, django

I want all the fields in my view.py details' function. The details function looks like

```
**Page views.py**
def page_detail(request, slug):

    details = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=slug)

    return render(request,'page/details.html', {'details': details})

**Page models.py**
class Page(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    dscription = models.TextField(blank=True) 
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/')
    ...
    ...

    def __str__(self):

        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("page:page_detail", kwargs= {"slug": self.slug })
```

Want to get all the field details in the views.py details function, but it depends on the models

**str** function. If I increase the number of the field in this **str** function I can get the value of all those fields, else not.

How to display all the fields. why get_object_or_404 depends on **str**
Please describe, thanks in advance.

Comment: pl show us your template code also

Comment: {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block body_block %}
{{details.title}} {{details.description}}    {% endblock %}

Comment: are you not getting data in {{details.title}} {{details.description}} fields?

Comment: If I print the details in views.py to check it in the console it just prints the title only. Not the other fields, if I increase the __str__ with: return '{} by {}'.format(self.title, self.created) 'only 2 fields r coming not all the fields.

Comment: what is the out put in templates?

Comment: [<Page: About Us>] I printed {{ details }} and in console [<Page: About Us>]

Comment: {{ details.title }}

{{ details.description }} If I do this only title gets printed. All the table fields have value.

Comment: You have a typo in your `description` field within your `Page` model definition. You wrote "`dscription`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried the same thing. My error was a blank slug was causing the confusion. But i doubt that could be the reason here.. 
There is a spelling mistake in your Description!

In model :
class Page(models.Model):

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,blank=True)
***dscription*** = models.TextField(blank=True) 
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/')
...
...
```

In view:
{{details.***description***}}